# Succinctness of regular expressions with empty word

Tags: reference-request, regular-expressions

Consider regular expressions on some alphabet $\Sigma$, without the empty word: $$e,f:=a\in\Sigma\mid e\cdot f \mid e+f\mid e^+$$

These $\varepsilon$⁻free expressions can define all regular languages that do not contain the empty word ($\varepsilon$-free languages).
Does it come at a cost in terms of expression size ? In particular, is there an exponential blow-up for translating a classical regular expression (with $\varepsilon$), that accepts an $\varepsilon$-free language, into an $\varepsilon$-free expression?

It could seem that for instance the expression $a_0(a_1+\varepsilon)(a_2+\varepsilon)(a_3+\varepsilon)\dots(a_n+\varepsilon)$ would require such an exponential blow-up. But actually it looks like we can use a recursive algorithm that splits the product in the middle, computes expressions $e,f$ for $(a_1+\varepsilon)\dots(a_{n/2}+\varepsilon)$ and $(a_{n/2+1}+\varepsilon)\dots(a_n+\varepsilon)$ respectively, and returns $(e+f+e\cdot f)$. This will produce an expression $E$ of quadratic size only, and we can return $a_0+a_0E$.

It seems non-trivial however to generalize this idea to any input expression, if possible.

Do you know of any reference on the subject?

Comment: Maybe $ab(c+\varepsilon)ab^2(c+\varepsilon)ab^3(c+\varepsilon)\dots$?

Comment: @xavierm02 That's $ab(ca+a)b^2(ca+a)b^3(ca+a)\dots$.

Comment: In your example, you don't actually need to split in the middle - anywhere would work, so you can split after the first concatenation. Maybe this can be used as a basis for an inductive argument?

Comment: @Shaull are you sure ? I believed if you always split at the first concatenation you will end up with an exponential formula, since you duplicate the formula returned on input of size $n-1$

Comment: @Denis - yeah, you're right. But you have to admire my persistence in suggesting answers to your questions, knowing full well anything I think of, you probably thought of already :)

Comment: The following paper deals with a similar but different question: Djelloul Ziadi: Regular Expression for a Language without Empty Word. Theor. Comput. Sci. 163(1&2): 309-315 (1996)
https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(96)00028-X Thanks  @Emil Jeřábek for pointing out my mistake - my answer will delete itself within 5 seconds, I will retain only this comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a fixed alphabet $\Sigma$, the blow-up is at most polynomial.

First, given a regular expression $r$, it is straightforward to construct an expression $\tilde r$ using the operators $a\in\Sigma$, $+$, $\cdot$, $(-)^+$, and $\let\nul\varnothing\nul$ such that
$$L(\tilde r)=L(r)\let\bez\smallsetminus\bez\{\let\ep\varepsilon\ep\}$$
recursively, by putting $\tilde a=a$, $\tilde\epsilon=\tilde\nul=\nul$, $\let\wt\widetilde\wt{r+s}=\tilde r+\tilde s$, $\wt{r^*}=\tilde r^+$, and
$$\wt{r\cdot s}=\tilde r\cdot\tilde s\underbrace{{}+\tilde r}_{\kern-1em\text{if }\ep\in L(s)\kern-1em}\overbrace{{}+\tilde s}^{\kern-1em\text{if }\ep\in L(r)\kern-1em}.$$
Unless $L(r)\subseteq\{\ep\}$, we can subsequently eliminate $\nul$ using $\nul+r=r+\nul=r$, $\nul\cdot r=r\cdot\nul=\nul^+=\nul$. Thus, if $r$ is a regular expression such that $\ep\notin L(r)\ne\nul$, then $\tilde r$ is an $\ep$-free regular expression as defined in the question such that $L(r)=L(\tilde r)$.

In general, the size of $\tilde r$ may be exponential in the size of $r$, but the *depth* of $\tilde r$ is linear in the depth of $r$. Crucially, every regular expression $r$ of size $n$ has an equivalent regular expression $s$ of depth $O(\log n)$ by Theorem 6.2 in

> Moses Ganardi, Markus Lohrey: *A universal tree balancing theorem*, ACM Transactions on Computation Theory 11 (2019), no. 1, article no. 1, 25 pp, doi [10.1145/3278158](https://doi.org/10.1145/3278158). Preprint [arXiv:1704.08705](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08705) [cs.CC].

Then $\tilde s$ also has depth $O(\log n)$, hence size $2^{O(\log n)}=n^{O(1)}$.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed this rewriting with a depth of $O(\log n)$ corresponds to "balancing the tree" of the expression, which can be viewed as a general formulation of the example I gave.